# scanf more then one variable

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

I have line like this 
and I am searching for how the input works when the code is executed

```
scanf("%d, %f",&withdrawal ,&balance );
```

I use Cygwin to compile the code and afterwards I am asked for inputs.
Does it mean that I have to write two numbers separated by space

```
60 120
```

or there is some trick to do that ?
It could be an easy question, but I just would like to understand how it works when it is asked for more then one input value.
Thanks

Comment: You need a comma too--"60, 120"

Comment: or remove `,` from `"%d, %f"`, change to `"%d %f"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf(), or scan formatted, expects input in the format you specified. scanf("%d, %f") simply means you expect input in this exact format, for example: 62, 2.15 .

Answer (score 0):

scanf expects an input as specified in quotes, as Matt Phillips mentioned. 
 
so, whether change a scanf to:

`scanf("%d %f", &withdrawal, &balance);` and then input `60 120` or just input `60, 120`

Answer (score 0):

On encountering non-white-space character (`,` in your case) in a format string (`"%d, %f"`), `scanf` compares it with the next input character.

> - If the two characters match, `scanf` discards the input character and continues processing the format string.
> - If the character doesn't match, `scanf` puts the offending character back into the input buffer and aborts without further processing the format string.

Therefore you need to input `60, 120.0` so that `scanf` read the input successfully.